# Coin Flip Help Required On Python Regarding Variables

Tags: python, variables

**Note: I have coded at school for gcse and stuff, im decent but rusty becuase i havent coded in ages. forgive my poor coding, if you can help make the code more efficient, thank you.**

*Situation: I am trying to code a simple coin flip game where the player starts with a balance and then can bet and double their money if they win the bet. however I cannot get the variables to add together, upon searching the internet no understandable answer could be found, someone please help me with a simple solution, thanks in advance, tom :)*

```
import random

print("Welcome to tomm's CSGOWild.com coinflip simulator!")
Starting_Money = input("How much money do you want to start with?")
Coin_Flip = random.randint(1, 2)

def Betting():

    Balance = ""
    Balance = Starting_Money + Balance
    Broke = "0"

    while Balance > Broke:

        Bet_Amount = input("How much money do you want to bet in this coin flip?")
        Coin_Side = input("What side do you want to choose: CT or T")
        Coin_Side_Coin = ""
        Temp_Balance = ""

        Coin = random.randint(1, 2)

        if Coin == 1:
        Coin_Side_Coin = "CT"

        elif Coin == 2:
        Coin_Side_Coin = "T"

        if Coin_Side == Coin_Side_Coin:
            Temp_Balance = Bet_Amount + Bet_Amount
            Balance = Balance + Temp_Balance
            print("Congratulations, you just won" + Temp_Balance + "in a coin flip!")

        elif Coin_Side != Coin_Side_Coin:
            Balance = Balance - Bet_Amount
            print("Sorry, you just lost" + Bet_Amount + "in a coin flip!")

Betting()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your money to be set as floats so things will add up properly. I'm sitting at a bar for NYE so I can't copy the whole code or test to make sure things work, but it should.

(If your user doesn't enter a float, a `TypeError` will be thrown. I recommend a `while` loop with input in a `try/catch` so you `break` if no exception is thrown.)

```
Starting_Money = float(input("How much money do you want to start with?"))

Balance = 0.0

Coin_Side_Coin = 0.0

Temp_Balance = 0.0
```

Comment: I was successful in adding the above things, however i ran into a problem where there is no was of verifying weather the user has enough money to bet on the coin flip, this means the user can bet 10000000 when he only has 10 in his balance, would you help again, thanks in advance tom :)

Comment: Take out the while loop and just have an if conditional testing if they have the money. If they don't, print a message and exit.